# Nested attributes showing when editing but not when creating a new record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-forms

When I edit a model with nested attributes everything works perfectly. If I try to create a new record with nested attributes, the nested attributes don't appear on the form that has the nested attributes. I have two models as follows

```
class JobSpec < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :availabilities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :availabilities, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_spec
end
```

in the `job_specs_controller` I have

```
class JobSpecsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @job_spec = JobSpec.new
    @availabilities = Availability.none
    availability = Availability.new
    availability.job_spec = @job_spec
    @availabilities << availability
  end

  def edit
    @job_spec = JobSpec.find(params[:id])
    @availabilities = @job_spec.availabilities
  end

  def job_spec_params
    params.require(:job_spec).permit(
      ... all of the job_spec attributes,
      availabilities_attributes: [:id, ... all of the availability attributes],
    )
  end
end
```

In `_form` for `job_spec` I have

```
  <% @availabilities.each do |availability| %>
    <%= f.fields_for availability do |builder| %>
      <%= render partial: 'availabilities/form_mini', 
        locals: {f: builder, availability: availability} %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Since editing works, I assume there's not much wrong. Any ideas?

**Update**

I've almost sorted out all the problems but still have one. Here's what I've done.

1) I had to build the `job_spec` `availabilities`. The new action of the `JobSpecsController` now looks like this

```
  def new
    @job_spec = JobSpec.new
    @job_spec.client_id = params[:client_id]
    @job_spec.availabilities.build
  end
```

2) I wanted to be able the destroy the nested models, so I had to pass `:_destroy` in with the nested attributes to `job_spec_params`. That method looks like this

```
  def job_spec_params
    params.require(:job_spec).permit(
      ... all of the job_spec attributes,
      availabilities_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, ... all of the availability attributes],
    )
  end
end
```

3) Finally, I had to change `_form` for `job_spec`. I have

```
<%= f.fields_for :availabilities do |builder| %>
  <%= render partial: 'availabilities/form_mini', locals: {f: builder} %>
<% end %>
```

The only issue I have now is that I want to pass and instance variable through to my availability partials. Something like this

```
<%= render partial: 'availabilities/form_mini', locals: {f: builder, a: availability} %>
```

How should that be done? I'm not sure how to iterate over all the `@availabilities` while rendering all the partials.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you worked some of the issues out. First one small improvement

```
#job_specs_controller.rb

def new
  @job_spec = JobSpec.new(client_id: params[:client_id])
  @job_spec.availabilities.build
end
```

And to overcome your last issue, the solution is a mix of what you had before and after. You can pass the actual object in the `fields_for` method. It's like that:

```
#_form.html.erb
<% @job_spec.availabilities.each do |availability| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :availabilities, availability do |builder| %>
    <%= render partial: 'availabilities/form_mini',
        locals: {f: builder, a: availability} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```